# Avoid passing variables to classes all the time

Tags: php, oop, static, global-variables

I'm creating a web app in PHP5. So far, I have two "global" variables: $input and $sql. $input is the validated and sanitized input from $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE. $sql is an instance of my mysql(i) class.

These two are needed in almost every other class. This could be relatively easily achieved by passing them as parameters to the __construct function of each class. But that seems ... clumsy. Along with more class specific parameters and potential future global vars, it makes for unwieldy function calls.

The easy and, as I understand it, noobie alternative would be using the global keyword. I don't want to do that. I get the downsides of globals, although in my scenario (small app) they wouldn't matter much. But it's also clumsy to explicitely label them global before using them again.

A more elegant way I suppose: I have a webapp class from which I extend all other classes. This webapp class holds common functions I need in more than one other class but that do not warrant for a seperate class.
If I store $input and $sql as static variables in this webapp master class, they'd be accessible in all subclasses.
But I understand that static variables are as much frowned upon, if not more, than global variables.

Is that true?
I guess I'm one of these people who overthink everything, but I like elegant code and this looks elegant to my (amateur) eyes.

Comment: Not sure if it is possible to answer your "question", but "Yes" we pass *dependencies* (it is actually the most important term here) over constructor (constructor injection) or methods (method injection)

Comment: @zerkms Alright then. If this is the best practice, I'll get used to it :o)

Answer (score 2):

> So far, I have two "global" variables

Yuck! Globals are bad. :-)

> $input is the validated and sanitized input from $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE

Why do you make that global. Simply sanitize / normalize / whatever when you really are going to use it.

> $sql is an instance of my mysql(i) class.

Again: no need to make that global. Use [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

> The easy and, as I understand it, noobie alternative would be using the global keyword. I don't want to do that.

You are right: you don't want to do that.

> A more elegant way I suppose: I have a webapp class from which I extend all other classes.

That also doesn't sound really correct. A class has a specific function (/ responsibility).

> But I understand that static variables are as much frowned upon

Static stuff are just globals with a different name.

If you do want to make your life easier you could implement a [dependency injection container](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html).

Answer (score -1):

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.patterns.php

This link describes the singleton pattern which is the oo-way which provides a single global instance of a class. I'm sure this is elegant enough seeing you will otherwise being subclassing for the sake of subclassing, and not requiring them to pass as a parameter.
This is what i would do :)

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa: even though I agree that singletons are "evil" - it is **better** than globals. At least by the fact that we may **control** them

Comment: @zerkms ok you have a small point about which is worse. However IMHO it's the difference between taking a bullet in your head or a spear (or something else lethal). :-)

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa: code with singletons is maintainable enough. It is difficult to test but easy enough to debug. So I cannot agree with your metaphor.

Comment: @zerkms: they are **worse** than globals.  Globals are implicitly global, you know that.  People still think that Singletons are not global (your comment proves that).  Singletons are harder to mock out and test than globals are.  So no, they are not better than anything...

Comment: @ircmaxell: I'm not sure where you have seen that I don't think they are global, but your mindreader is broken. PS: I also said they are difficult to test

Answer (score -1):

Personally I would employ the singleton in this example. Singletons can be frowned upon however when used in the right situation they are perfectly fine.

I would create your "WebApp" class as a singleton, this means where ever you need those variables you simple access the "WebApp".

If you have never used a singletone before, here is an example:

```
class WebApp
{
    private static $instance = null;
    private $post_data = array();

    private function WebApp(){}

    public static function instance(){
        if(!isset(WebApp::$instance))
            WebApp::$instance = new WebApp();
        return WebApp::$instance;
    }
}

print_r(WebApp::instance()->post_data);
```

Comment: See my [other comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564443/avoid-passing-variables-to-classes-all-the-time/10564464#comment-13675390) about why singletons are bad.

Comment: I completely disagree. Anyone who just says "pattern X is bad" doesn't have a clue what they are talking about. While I will agree people can tend to over use the singleton hence why it gets this bad reputation there is a time and a place for every pattern, and in this users example this is that place.

Comment: @AdamThornton: while I generally agree that absolutions are a bad thing, in this case, I completely agree with @RepWhoringPeeHaa...  Show me a case where a singleton is appropriate, and I'll show you that your architecture is flawed.  It gets a bad reputation because Singletons have no place in `OOP`.  Now, if you're doing Class Oriented Programming, fine.  But in OOP, they have absolutely no place...